# Most pythonic way of getting index of the last list item

Tags: python

Given a list:

```
l1 = [0, 211, 576, 941, 1307, 1672, 2037]
```

What is the most pythonic way of getting the index of the last element of the list. Given that Python lists are zero-indexed, is it:

```
len(l1) - 1
```

Or, is it the following which uses Python's list operations:

```
l1.index(l1[-1])
```

Both return the same value, that is 6.

Comment: `len(l1) - 1` - is definitely faster (more effective)

Comment: It's also more effective in that it's not wrong if the last item is duplicated earlier in the list.

Comment: Almost certainly it's the former. Using the latter requires an indexing into the list and a function call. The former is simply a function call. It's also more obvious.

Comment: The last technique `l1.index(l1[-1])` isn't always guaranteed to work, if there are duplicates in your list, you might have to use `l1.rindex(l1[-1])` to make it fool-proof. Although I prefer `len(l1) - 1` both for readability and efficiency.

Comment: `len([]) - 1` is is -1  so none of your solutions will always work correctly.

Comment: May I ask why you need the last indice in the first place? usually just doing `l1[-1]` will get the last value, why do you need the indice other then `-1`?

Comment: I am doing a conversion of days since an event to years since said event. I am storing the days in a list such that the index of the list directly gives the years. A dictionary will not work as I need to compare values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the first is correct:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
>>> len(lst) - 1
4
>>> lst.index(lst[-1])
0
```

However it depends on what do you mean by "the index of the last element".

Note that `index` must traverse the whole list in order to provide an answer:

```
In [1]: %%timeit lst = list(range(100000))
   ...: lst.index(lst[-1])
   ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop

In [2]: %%timeit lst = list(range(100000))
len(lst)-1
   ...: 
The slowest run took 80.20 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 109 ns per loop
```

Note that the second timing is in **nanoseconds** versus **milliseconds** for the first one.

Comment: This answer comprehensively captures the twin issues in the problem I asked: the issue of duplicates and speed. Thanks to all who answered and clarified my doubt.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the first. Why?

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,3]
>>> l1.index(l1[-1])
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Bakuriu's answer is great!

In addition, it should be mentioned that you rarely need this value. There are usually other and better ways to do what you want to do. Consider this answer as a sidenote :)

As you mention, getting the last element can be done this way:

```
lst = [1,2,4,2,3]
print lst[-1]  # 3
```

If you need to iterate over a list, you should do this:

```
for element in lst:
    # do something with element
```

If you still need the index, this is the preferred method:

```
for i, element in enumerate(lst):
    # i is the index, element is the actual list element
```

Comment: I did not want to use enumerate() as I was not really interested in traversing the entire list, knew that it was the last element I wanted. However as Bakuriu and others have pointed out, it effectively is way more work as it also involves value comparison etc. The reason I had this doubt was whether is is acceptable in Python programming to do stuff like len(list)  - 1 :)

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that :) Can I ask in what context you want to get this value? I can't think of a usecase myself